# Create a new issue using YouTrackSharp

Tags: youtrack, youtracksharp

I'm trying to create a new issue using YouTrackSharp, back into my on premise you track instance. I can search fine, so I know my Connection and Credentials are working.

Based on the [example](http://blog.jetbrains.com/youtrack/2011/06/youtracksharp-a-net-client-for-youtrack/) I have tried both a dynamic, as well as instantiating an Issue().

Fails to Compile

```
dynamic issue = new Issue()
{
    type = "Question",
    summary = model.Summary,
    description = model.Description,
    projectShortName = "CSR",
};
```

This code compiles, but Fails at runtime to convert dynamic into Issue param, with exception ' The best overloaded method match for **'YouTrackSharp.Issues.IssueManagement.CreateIssue(YouTrackSharp.Issues.Issue)' has some invalid arguments**

```
dynamic issue = new
{
    type = "Question",
    summary = model.Summary,
    description = model.Description,
    projectShortName = "CSR",
};
YouTrackIssueManager().CreateIssue(issue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Find The Answer** I found on the [github repo](https://github.com/JetBrains/YouTrackSharp) about Breaking changed in 2.0 - and then it goes on to talk about [reading the specs](https://github.com/JetBrains/YouTrackSharp/blob/master/src/YouTrackSharp.Specs/Specs/IssueManagementSpecs.cs) for examples.

Exerpt:

> Issue is now a dynamic type. To work with it, you need to declare an
>   issue as dynamic. The only fixed field it has is "Id" (although later
>   on some others might be added). The reason for this is that it is now
>   inline with how YouTrack works itself which is that every field in an
>   issue is basically a custom field. You can now have as many or as
>   little custom fields as you like! This was a major change in 2.0 and
>   is incompatible with existing code unfortunately.

**The answer/code that worked is**, using a combination of Dynamic and new Issue() (which was new syntax for me, that i'm now looking further into).

```
dynamic issue = new Issue();
issue.Type = "Question";
issue.Summary = model.Summary;
issue.Description = model.Description;
issue.ProjectShortName = "CSR";
YouTrackIssueManager().CreateIssue(issue);
```

Thanks [@hhariri](https://twitter.com/hhariri) for your work on this project.